# Ignoring phone number if 1 is at the front

Tags: text, server, phone-number, mass-assignment

I am trying to send out a text message to phone numbers. It works as long as it is under 11 digits, but if the phone number has 11 digits it fails. Is there a way to be flexible for both?

```
$phonenum = "16783293991"; //works if 6783293991
  $from_name = "Gregory Smith";
    $from_email = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $from = sprintf ("From: %s <%s>\nSender: %s <%s>\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n", $from_name, $from_email, $from_name, $from_email);
  $to = $phonenum;
$formatted_number = $to."@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
mail("$formatted_number", "", "$message", $from); //the empty field of "" is the subject line and is unnecessary
```

Comment: `if (substr($phonenumber, 0, 1) == '1') { continue; }`?

Comment: So, I should find out if the first digit is a 1 and then remove it...Should I check the length instead?

Comment: well if you're dealing with north american numbers only, then all numbers could potentially start with 1, since that's the N.A. country code. but checking for length can't hurt. e.g. sprint's not gonna know what to do with 8675309@messaging...

Comment: $ch = strlen ( $phonenum ); echo $ch;
if ($ch === "11") {   echo shows that it is 11 characters long, but this comparison check fails

Comment: because $ch is an integer, `===` is the strict comparison operation. type AND value. `'42' === 42` is false, because it's string==int, `'42' == 42` is true, because the values match. do either `$ch === 42` or `$ch == '42'`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Put that in an answer so that I can give you credit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `1` as the first digit, and verify length:

```
if ((substr($phone, 0 , 1) == '1') && (strlen($phone) <= 11)) {
   sms stuff here
}
```